# raise keyword in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am new to python programming.is it possible to raise exception in python without using try except block (or)only with except (or)only with try block.

Thanks
Mukthyar

Comment: @marc_s I told him many times, but he doesn't seem to care that one day, no one will help him any longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need it to be in a try..except block but when you raise an exception you always want to catch it and handle it somewhere in your code. That is the use of the try..except block. You would need to use it somewhere in your code to handle the raised exception else the exception will halt the execution of your program.

Answer (score 3):

You can raise an exception at any point in your code, and it will exit all functions going up the call chain until it gets to a matching except block. You don't need to be *inside* a try block to *raise* an exception - only to catch one.

The full set of things you can have on a try block looks like this:

```
try:
    ...
except A:
    ...
except B:
   ...
else:
   ...
finally:
   ...
```

You can find a full definition of all of these in the docs, but I think the bit you're asking about is whether you can have `except:` without `try:` - you can't. The `try:` is mandatory in the above, and you need at least one of the others, but it can be any of them (and you can have more than one, including arbitarily many `except:`s).

Answer (score 2):

Read the documentation on [Errors and Exceptions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html), particularly [Raising Exceptions section](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions)

> The `raise` statement allows the programmer to force a specified
>   exception to occur. For example:
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> raise NameError('HiThere')
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
> NameError: HiThere
> ```

Comment: This is good advice but it belongs best in a comment to the question. Answers should answer the question that was asked. This just presents an off-site link. The [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) says a little more and in particular calls out answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site" as being prone to deletion.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: it's not a real question anyway...

Comment: So you voted to close as not a real question but then answered anyway. That's odd.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: No, it isn't. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4283/closing-etiquette-why-do-some-answer-and-close

Comment: The accepted answer there talks about off-topic close votes. I suspect that it pre-dates the feature to make off-topic close votes with migration suggestions that then lead to automatic migration. But in this case you stated that the question "cannot be reasonably answered in its current form", and then proceeded to answer. I'm sorry, but that is odd. Perhaps you changed your mind and now feel that the question is a real question. That's understandable. We all make close votes that we regret.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/ Well, unfortunately *"general reference"* close reason didn't get implemented. You are free to ask for clarifications on Meta.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be inside a `try/except` block in order to raise an exception. On the other hand, if you want to catch and handle an exception then you do need to use a `try/except` block.

It is a syntax error to write `try` without either `except` or `finally`. Or indeed to write `except` without its matching `try`. These language constructs are inextricably linked.